# How to control which fixture combinations are used to parametrized tests?

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

In conftest.py, I have three fixtures.

Two of them are initialized with lists parameters.
And one of them uses the two previous fixtures like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(params = servers_list)
def server_fixture(request):
    server = request.param[0]
    print(server)
    yield server

@pytest.fixture(params = users_list)
def user_fixture(request):
    user = request.param[0]
    print(user)
    yield user

@pytest.fixture()
def login_fixture(server_fixture, user_fixture):
    #Some code
```

The lists data come from outsourcing lists and they look like this:

```
server_list = [path1, path2]
users_list =  [user1, user2]
```

I have one test in my test file (test_opertaion.py) which uses login_fixture like this:

```
def test_my_permission(login_fixture):
    #some code
```

If I run pytest, it will collect 4 tests, which cover all the possible scenarios according to my parameters:

```
test_my_permission[path1, user1]
test_my_permission[path1, user2]
test_my_permission[path2, user1]
test_my_permission[path2, user2]
```

I would like to control the scenarios to not receive all the options.

For example, I know that `user2` doesn't exist on `path2` so I don't want my test to run on the `test_my_permission[path2, user2]`.

How can I do so?

I decided to create a JSON file which reflects my desired scenarios as following:

```
{
    "['path1';'path2']": "['user1']",
    "['path1']": "['user2']"
}
```

After that, I decided to write some iteration code, to read my data from the JSON file, inside the conftest.py file (maybe this is not the right place) in order to receive the desired scenarios and to set my parameters as following:

```
 scenario 1 : "['path1';'path2']" to servers_list parameter and
              "['user1']" to users_list parameter.
              This scenario should collect two tests.
 scenario 2 : "['path1']" to servers_list parameter and
              "['user2']" to users_list parameter.
              This scenario should collect one test.
```

The problem is that pytest takes only the last scenario and therefore collects only one test.

Is there anyone who knows how to solve this issue?

Alternatively, is there anyone who has an idea how to control my desired scenarios?

Comment: Are the `server_fixture` and `user_fixture` used anywhere else? Is there a reason the combinations can't be parametrized in the test itself, rather than on the fixtures?

Comment: server_fixture  and user_fixture  are use only as a baseline to login_fixture and also for another fixtures which I didn't mentioned in the example. This is the reason I can not use the parameters in the test itself.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would have [parametrized](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/parametrize.html#pytest-mark-parametrize-parametrizing-test-functions) the supported combinations/scenarios of servers and users *directly into the test* *itself*. The `.parametrize` function's 2nd argument accepts any iterable, so you can define your `path_` and `user_` pairs somewhere else, for example, define and read it from a config file:

```
@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "server, user",
    [
        ("path1", "user1"),
        ("path1", "user2"),
        ("path2", "user1"),
    ],
)
def test_my_permission(server, user):
    pass
```

```
tests/test_main.py::test_my_permission[path1-user1] PASSED
tests/test_main.py::test_my_permission[path1-user2] PASSED
tests/test_main.py::test_my_permission[path2-user1] PASSED
```

But, since you [clarified in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72173416/pytest-conftest-py-how-to-custom-parameters-to-fixtures#comment127519564_72173416) that you'd want to reuse `server_fixture` and `user_fixture` and "*cannot use the parameters in the test itself.*", another option is to manually check the `path_` and `user_` combination in  `login_fixture` and [`skip`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest-skip) it if it's not a valid combination:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def login_fixture(server_fixture, user_fixture):
    if server_fixture == "path2" and user_fixture == "user2":
        pytest.skip(reason="path2 and user2 combination is not valid")
    pass

def test_my_permission(login_fixture):
    pass
```

```
tests/test_main.py::test_my_permission[path1-user1] PASSED
tests/test_main.py::test_my_permission[path1-user2] PASSED
tests/test_main.py::test_my_permission[path2-user1] PASSED
tests/test_main.py::test_my_permission[path2-user2] SKIPPED (path2 and user2 combination is not valid)
```

This isn't that elegant, and only works as long as the skipped combination check in `login_fixture` applies to all the tests that uses that fixture. The upside is that the test results report *clearly* shows that a `path2` + `user2` test input was considered, but the combination is not a valid test case.

Similar to what you did, you can factor out the combinations into a JSON file:

```
# scenarios.json

{
    "login_scenarios": [
        ["path1", "user2"],
        ["path1", "user1"],
        ["path2", "user1"]
    ]
}
```

Then just read that into the test:

```
with open("scenarios.json") as f:
    scenarios = json.load(f)
login_scenarios = scenarios["login_scenarios"]

@pytest.fixture()
def login_fixture(server_fixture, user_fixture):
    combination = [server_fixture, user_fixture]
    if combination not in login_scenarios:
        pytest.skip(reason=f"{combination} combination is not valid")
    pass
```

An alternative to skipping is to implement one of pytest's collection [hooks](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#hooks) that gets called to parametrize each test: [`pytest_generate_tests`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#hooks). That hook receives a [`MetaFunc`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html#metafunc) object, which contains the fixtures requested by each test. Based on the requested fixtures, you can dynamically set the right combination of `server` and `user`.

Put this in the **conftest.py**:

```
# In tests/conftest.py

import json

with open("scenarios.json") as f:
    scenarios = json.load(f)
login_scenarios = scenarios["login_scenarios"]

def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    if {"server", "user"} <= set(metafunc.fixturenames):
        metafunc.parametrize(
            "server, user",
            login_scenarios,
        )
```

Then define the test and fixtures as:

```
# In tests/test_main.py

@pytest.fixture()
def login_fixture(server, user):
    pass

def test_my_permission(login_fixture):
    pass
```

That would limit the generated parametrized tests to:

```
tests/test_main.py::test_my_permission[path1-user1] PASSED
tests/test_main.py::test_my_permission[path1-user2] PASSED
tests/test_main.py::test_my_permission[path2-user1] PASSED
```

...without the `path2` + `user2` combination.

Again, same as before, you can define and read the test scenarios from an external file and pass it to `.parametrize`. Note that the hook gets called to parametrize *all* the tests in the target directory, so you need to check if the requesting test *does* require the `server` and `user` fixtures.